# Some Linear layout child cannot scroll inside Coordinator Layout

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

I Have a problem with Linear Layout Child

[image: This is my coordinator tree]

[image: This is my layout design]

with this layout settings, i can scroll when i scroll on RecyclerView,

But i cannot scroll the layout if i touch and scroll on TextView above the RecycleView

here is the layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/AppBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderLayout
                android:id="@+id/slider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="#00ffffff"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPhone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="+62 (021) 8200000"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/AppBarLayout"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/AppBarLayout" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtAddress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean imperdiet aliquet justo. Vestibulum euismod eu sem eget tristique. Mauris egestas porta lorem ornare posuere."
            app:layout_anchor="@id/txtPhone"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtPhone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Review"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtAddress" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/reviewList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <uk.co.markormesher.android_fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:buttonIcon="@drawable/ic_add"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|center" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

the behaviour that i expected is, i can scroll either i touch in "txtPhone" or "txtAddress" or "txtView5" and also in "reviewList"

any idea?

Comment: you should add the textviews as recyclerview items to achieve smooth scroll

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to wrap the LinearLayout inside a NestedScrollView layout.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
..
..
..
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```